# Deploy apps to Sharepoint 2013 on-premises

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I don't know how to deploy my apps to SharePoint server 2013.
I have installed SharePoint 2013 in the server.
I am accessing the server from my laptop.
I am using CSOM to create apps and deploying into server.
I have tried it using SharePoint online code is working perfectly.
I don't know how to execute the same code in SharePoint on-premises.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your [environment properly](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for Apps?

It involves starting the Subscription Settings and App Management services as well as some DNS(and possibly firewall) configuration and [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/06/14/prepare-your-sharepoint-2013-farm-for-app-development-and-debugging.aspx) does a good job of detailing it.

After having your environment set up, you need to upload your App to the App Catalog and install it to the Site.

Answer (score 0):

For deploying app you need to create a virtual domain or sub domain. This domain will be used to deploy the application on **on premise** server.

You need to configure and start below services.

1. App Management
2. Microsoft Subscription Service (this service can be start only through code.)

After creating Virtual Domain and starting these services, you need to configure the App Center Settings in Central Admin.

The next step is to publish your app on App Center, for this VS2013 will give you publish app file, which you need to upload on app center. Trust it with your server while asking. Then allow users to view this app.

Hope it Will help you.